# Donald Trump's Hamburger

Tags: halacha, bishul-akum

While visiting Japan, Donald Trump was served a hamburger at a lunch with the Japanese Prime Minister. (See [here](http://mashable.com/2017/11/06/trump-beef-america-japan/#.aSnUY3cZPqK).)

One of the halachos of *bishul akum*, the restriction of eating even kosher food which was cooked by a non-Jew, is that it is only a problem if the food is *oleh al shulchan melachim*, it would be served at a royal table (Y.D. 113:1). This standard has commonly been applied in modern times as that which would be eaten at a state dinner (see [here](https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/2168/food-fit-for-a-king-reviewing-the-laws-of-bishul-akum-and-bishul-yisroel/) for example).

Does Trump's hamburger mean that now hamburgers are subject to the restrictions of *bishul akum* in Japan? Does one ruler's culinary taste, particularly if it determined the menu of a diplomatic meal, affect the status of *oleh al shulchan melachim*?

Comment: The Star-K article you quoted seems to say pretty clearly that it is subjective, and seemingly, if that's something that is served during a state function, it would be a problem. Also, if I had to guess, I would assume that hamburgers were always under the restriction of Bishul Akum. It's a slab of meat, the fact that you place it between two pieces of bread wouldn't no longer make it Bishul Akum (source: pure conjecture).

Comment: @Salmononius2 see here http://www.haoros.com/Archive/index.asp?kovetz=912&cat=9&haoro=11 about general hamburger status for bishul akum

Comment: I have heard this argument before http://matzav.com/rav-elyashiv-obama-and-french-fries/

Comment: I think the concept of *Shulchan Melachim* has a far different concept than what President Trump ate in Japan. First, I believe that when they refer to *melachim* they mean a king that has a palace with servants and rules the country on his own as that. Saudi Arabia would prob. qualify as such as place and prob. Jordan. There's a debate as to whether any U.S. President would be considered, halachically, a king. Secondly, in this situation, it seems that they specifically accommodated Trump's culinary preference.  Japanese kings may prefer sushi vs. hamburgers.

Comment: @DanF You're free to believe what you want to believe, but it's against the consensus of most major poskim today.

Comment: @danF, do you think the president doesn't have a palace and servants?  Also, why would that be relevant?  I understand the method of rule has impact, though usually more for things like whether you say blessing on seeing this person.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen FIne, I get your point, here. My hunch is that the ruling goes according to what the leader of the host country usually eats or serves, not what is accommodated to some other visiting leader, esp. if this is not customary for them. E.g., if Bibi came and they served him galla and chulent, I don't think that would be considered common Japanese royal table food.

Answer (score 4):

As you pointed out from Rabbi Heinemann, it would only apply if this was served at a state dinner, which this was certainly not.  According to other Poskim, who take "Oleh al Shulchan Melachim" literally, if we assume that a president has the status of a king, it would now be prohibited.

If we assume that a Melech refers only to a king, and not to a president, see page 41 of [this paper](http://www.rambish.org.il/journals/k/kovetz_maamarim_magal/vol001/kovetz_maamarim_magal_01005.pdf) which brings a Machlokes as to whether or not "Sarim" of a particular place would have the status of Melchim for this Halachah.  Kaf Hachaim and others (Based on Arizal) say that a local important ruler's table is considered Shulchan Melachim, whereas the Divrei Yatziv seems to disagree with this:

> כף החיים יו"ד סימן קיג ס"ק ב
>   וגם עולה על שלחן מלכים וכו', לאו דוקא מלכים **אלא אפילו עולה על שלחן שרים
>   שבארץ ההיא אסור**. רבינו האר"י ז"ל בספר טעמי המצות פרשת עקב ובשה"מ
>   פרשת וילך. ברכי יוסף בשיורי ברכה אות ב' ור"ל אנשים חשובים שראוי מאכל זה
>   לתת לפניהם.
>
> שו"ת דברי יציב חלק יורה דעה סימן ל
>   יג( ויש להעיר בדבר שכתבתם שמבשלין להם ביצים, שצריך לברר בזה, הגם
>   שבליקוטי תורה פרשת עקב ]בטעמי המצוות[, ובשער המצוות פרשת וילך, דלאו
>   דוקא מלכים דה"ה כשהשררות אוכלין אותן, ובכף החיים ]סי' קי"ג סק"ב[ דר"ל
>   חשובים, **לא ידעתי מנ"ל הא, דפשיטא דחשובים ומלכים ושרים אינו גדר אחד**.

Comment: You are assuming the President and the Prime Minister have the status of Sarim and not Melachim? I think you need to support that assumption. Both are the highest office in their respective lands.

Comment: @Yez excellent point, I'll edit it in.

Comment: @Y  e  z I'm unaware of any country in the world having a king or queen where they are democratically elected by the populace. Perhaps, that definition is the halachic distinction and makes Trump, Bibi, and numerous others halachically non-kings.